# How to validate child serializer that requires data from parent in django rest framework nested serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using [DRF Writable Nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested)  to create writable nested serializer.

I need to validate 'ItemDetail' but it requires 'product_id' which is present in the parent serializer i.e. 'InvoiceItem'.

Models

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="invoice_items"
    )


class ItemDetail(models.Model):
    invoice_item = models.ForeignKey(
        InvoiceItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_details"
    )
    size = models.ForeignKey(
        Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_details"
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Serializers

```
class InvoiceItemSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    product = ProductMiniSerializer(read_only=True)
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    item_details = ItemDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceItem
        fields = [
            "id",
            "product_id",
            "product",
            "item_details",
        ]


class ItemDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ItemDetail
        fields = [
            "id",
            "size",
            "quantity",
        ]

    def validate(self, data):
        return item_detail_validate(self, data)
```

Validator

```
def item_detail_validate(self, data):
    # How to get product_id here so I can use it in a query
    return data
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a little late but for anyone else coming here, use the following when dealing with `many=True`

```py
def validate(self, data):
    product_id = self.parent.parent.initial_data['product_id']
    return item_detail_validate(self, data)
```

Usually when making a related reference, `self.parent.initial_data` can fetch the data from the parent serializer. However, when we use `many=True`, DRF implicitly calls the `ListSerializer`. It passes the child serializer to `ListSerializer`, which is then passed to the parent serializer

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer

Comment: `.root` is also available, which climbs the `.parent` tree until it reaches the top

Comment: @Ryan and answer author, Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Access the [**`initial_data`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance) attribute of serializer's parent,

```
def validate(self, data):
    product_id = self.parent.initial_data['product_id']
    return item_detail_validate(self, data)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'ItemDetailSerializer' object has no attribute 'initial_data'

Comment: what about `self.parent.initial_data['product_id']`

Comment: Now getting following error: 'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'initial_data'